# Can't capture first CRLF with raw IO::console

Tags: ruby, io, console

I'm trying to get input from the console using `IO::console::getch` in a loop but `getch` doesn't seem to capture the first linefeed (I need to hit enter twice for the loop to break), while `getc` does, but doesn't work with the rest of what I want to do.

How do I capture the first CRLF so I don't need to hit enter twice?

Relevant code:

```
require 'io/console'

buffer,str=IO::console(),""
loop do
    buffer.write "\r\033[32m"+str+"\033[0m"
    chr=buffer.getch

    break if chr=="\r"
    str+=chr
end
print "\n"+str
```

Comment: You don't say what OS you're on but usually you'll only see CRLF on Windows. Linux and Mac OS only use `"\n"`. It might help if you'd explain what you're trying to do as normally people aren't trying to write to console or read single characters using `getch` so it looks like you're making more work for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the source for [Highline](https://github.com/JEG2/highline)'s System Extensions module, I figured out that I can use `WinAPI._getch` on Windows and `STDIN.getbyte` on Unix to accomplish what I wanted to (obviously not complete code as I haven't checked for `SIGINT` or anything of the like yet).

```
require 'highline/system_extensions'
include HighLine::SystemExtensions

# assign getchar as a lambda based on OS
if (/mingw|win|emx/=~RUBY_PLATFORM)!=nil
    getchar=lambda{WinAPI._getch} # Windows
else
    getchar=lambda{STDIN.getbyte} # Unix
end

str="" # empty string to start
loop do
    # write the string to STDOUT in green as a test
    STDOUT.write "\r\033[32m"+str+"\033[0m"
    # call the lambda, convert to character
    chr=getchar[].chr

    return str if chr=="\r"
    str+=chr
end
```